# Multiple type for a variable in spark using scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I am working on a Spark project with scala. I want to train a model which can be k_means, gaussian_mixture, logistic regression, naive_bayes etc. But I cannot define a generic model as a return type. Since these algorithms' types are different like GaussianMixtureModel, KMeansModel etc. I cannot find any logical way to return this trained model.

Here is a peace of code from the project:

```
model.model_algorithm match {

      case "k_means" =>

        val model_k_means = k_means(data, parameters)

      case "gaussian_mixture" =>

        val model_gaussian_mixture = gaussian_mixture(data, parameters)

      case "logistic_regression" =>

        val model_logistic_regression = logistic_regression(data, parameters)  

}
```

So is there a way to return this trained model or to define a generic model that accepts all types?

Comment: what is it that you want to _do_ with the trained model? These classes all extend `org.apache.spark.mllib.util.Saveable`, `AntRef` and `Any`, so your method can return any of these types, but that won't necessarily help you. If you want to perform action X on these results later, you might want to create a trait `ModelResult` with method X, make this pattern-matching return `ModelResult`, and have three implementations of that trait, each handling a different model.

Comment: I tried to make them of type Any but predict() method cannot be used in that case. Can you please explain how can I implement pattern-matching in this case. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: So you have actually initiated three models and pattern matching to know which one runs. If such is the case,it's bad practice.

Comment: I should return one of machine learning models in a function, and using this model I want to make some prediction on a sample data. I know it is not the true way, defining each model in this way; however I cannot find a solution to this situation since I cannot return a model without knowing its type explicitly in run time.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a common Interface to wrap all your internal logic of training and predicting and just expose a simple interface to be reused.

```
trait AlgorithmInterface extends Serializable {
  def train(data: RDD[LabeledPoint])
  def predict(record: Vector)
}
```

And have Algorithms implemented in classes like

```
class LogisticRegressionAlgorithm extends AlgorithmInterface {
  var model:LogisticRegressionModel = null
  override def train(data: RDD[LabeledPoint]): Unit = {
    model = new LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS()
      .setNumClasses(10)
      .run(data)
  }
  override def predict(record:Vector): Double = model.predict(record)
}

class GaussianMixtureAlgorithm extends AlgorithmInterface {
  var model: GaussianMixtureModel = null
  override def train(data: RDD[LabeledPoint]): Unit = {
    model = new GaussianMixture().setK(2).run(data.map(_.features))
  }
  override def predict(record: Vector) = model.predict(record)
}
```

Implementing it

```
    // Assigning the models to an Array[AlgorithmInterface]
    val models: Array[AlgorithmInterface] = Array(
      new LogisticRegressionAlgorithm(),
      new GaussianMixtureAlgorithm()
    )
    // Training the Models using the Interfaces Train Function
    models.foreach(_.train(data))
    //Predicting the Value
    models.foreach( model=> println(model.predict(vectorData)))
```